# Listview with items which have drawable background has poor performance

Tags: android, listview, drawable

I have a `listview` with items having some fancy shadow background that I defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1.2dp" android:right="1.2dp" android:bottom="1.2dp" android:left="1.2dp" />
            <solid android:color="#02000000" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1.2dp" android:right="1.2dp" android:bottom="1.2dp" android:left="1.2dp" />
            <solid android:color="#05000000" />
            <corners android:radius="7dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This works and is nice, but applying it as the background of the items of a listview makes its performance poor slowing it down. For the items I define the background in my item.xml, which is (without textviews, images):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
  >
```

If I set the android:background value to a color, it works fine, so the problem is definitely that every single time the `listview` refreshes, it has to load the `drop_shadow`.xml drawable.
My question is if it can be optimized somehow? For example it is the same situation as using a custom typeface in the items, I have to create a TypefaceCahce and load the typefaces from it so it only needs to load it once not every time the listview refreshes. Is there a similar solution for drawables?

Comment: can you add how you are getting the views in the list view adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these in your ListView XML:

```
android:scrollingCache="false"
android:animationCache="false"
```